# Partial text match in Excel with an exclude condition

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a sumifs formula in excel to do a partial text match on campaign names. I'm facing an issue with partial text match when i have to do a text match on "Men" or "Women" as women also contains men in it thus overlapping the data. My campaigns names are like this :

```
XXXXX Men Deo SP (Auto)
YYYYYY Women Deo SP (Auto)
```

The simplified version of the formula im using is this :

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"*Men Deo*")
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"*Women Deo*")
```

where C:C is the columns that needs to be summed and A:A is the column which contains the campaign names.

I'd appreciate if you can help me structure this formula so that the sumifs for the men deo does not include the women deo data.

Comment: Add space before and after search pattern. I.e. "* Men *"

Comment: You might need to do it two ways in case Men comes at the beginning of a string like =SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"* Men Deo*")+SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"Men Deo*")